# Display values from database

Tags: android

I am pretty much new to Android application. I have a question to ask. My XML file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Name"
            android:padding="0px" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
       <EditText
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="250px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Is there a way i can assign values to EditText using java code and then display it. Basically all i want to do is to get value from database and display it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try reading this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

In your `onStart`/`onResume` method, add code like this:

```
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
e.setText("TEST");
```

Take a look at the samples in your SDK.